# Make images in <canvas> move with javascript keyboard input?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to do something that seems like it should be really simple, but I've been hitting a wall. I want to write javascript code which takes a image that has been drawn inside the the canvas tag and moves it via keyboard input. When I press the right arrow key, I want the image to move right. When I press the left arrow key, I want the image to move left. I want it to keep moving until I release the key, I'm not interested in something that just slides over a bit with each key press. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
<html>
<body onload="load_image()">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="240" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
<img id="testpic" src="testpic.png">
</canvas>

<script>
function load_image() {
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("testpic");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
// CODE THAT STARTS LEFT IMAGE MOVEMENT GOES HERE.
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
// CODE THAT STARTS RIGHT IMAGE MOVEMENT GOES HERE.
    }
}, true);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
// CODE THAT STOPS LEFT IMAGE MOVEMENT GOES HERE.
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
// CODE THAT STOPS RIGHT IMAGE MOVEMENT GOES HERE.
    }
}, true);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've been trying examples from several websites, but none of them work. The best I can do is redraw the image over and over with key presses, which will not work for me. Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated. If you present me with working code, I will love you!

Comment: "The best I can do is redraw the image over and over with key presses, which will not work for me". I'm sorry to say that you can't have it any other way. To get something to animate in canvas, you need to redraw it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: So, HTML5 canvas is really that ghetto? You have to remove/redraw over and over just to get a sliding image effect? That seems ridiculous to me.

Comment: That's not ghetto. That's how all animation works. With CSS, you (the programmer), don't have access to that level of the animation.
It's how your computer is putting images on your monitor. It's drawing them over and over again at roughly 60x a second.

Comment: http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful Read and learn

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I am aware of that, but I've seen plenty of examples of image menus smoothly sliding in and out. I assumed there was a easier way of animating them then painstakingly programming it frame by frame or with loops. Like, I don't know, CSS transform methods. :P

SerCrAsH, Thanks for the link, but the example they give is for mouse input, I've been looking for something that works with keydown/keyup.

Comment: There are animation libraries which abstract the minutia of canvas redraws, but at it's most basic that is what's happening. Take a look at what @SerCrAsH linked. It will be helpful to what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a working fiddle of what you want here: https://jsfiddle.net/uu4jqpqy/1/

The main point is that you have to have `setInterval` do a loop of redraws in the right direction on a key down, and key up clears that Interval:

```
if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    // CODE THAT STARTS LEFT IMAGE MOVEMENT GOES HERE.
    if(!leftPointer) {
        leftPointer = setInterval(function () {
            xval = xval - 1;
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img,xval,yval);
        }, speed)
    }
}
```

and

```
if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    // CODE THAT STOPS LEFT IMAGE MOVEMENT GOES HERE.
    clearInterval(leftPointer);
}
```

You also have to make some of the variables in an outer scope to get this to work.

Comment: YES! Thank you, this looks like it will do the trick... Question tho, how come the EventListener quits working in the fiddle? I'll consider this answered if I can get this working on my test page. BTW, I'm a gen1 Transformers fan too! :D

Comment: Awesome, Transformers all the way dude - In the jsfiddle site, you have to click into the output panel first, near the canvas image, for the key listeners to work, if that's what you mean

Comment: Ah no, I see what you mean, I forgot to clear the variables after clearing the interval, updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uu4jqpqy/2/

Comment: It totally works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!